# How to use "dateRestrict" parameter in Custom Search API

Tags: java, google-custom-search

I am trying to modify some java code which uses the Google API. One of the features I have not been able to get is the dateRestrict. Information about this can be found here: 

[GoogleAPI](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest#query-params)

To implement this I attach the following string after my query. It is properly connected with the full URL because other parameters work with it.

`String parameters = "&dateRestrict=2012-01-01";`

I have also tried 1d and 1m but those don't work either as parameters

If someone could show me of an example of dateRestrict I would greatly appreciate it. I just don't understand how they mean to use it in the API. Thank you.

Comment: according to the doc you linked to, the values should be "d1" and "m1".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On the [Using REST to Invoke the API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest#st_params) you can find information about `dateRestrict` parameter. Notes about parameter: Restricts results to URLs based on date. Supported values include:

- d[number]: requests results from the specified number of past days.
- w[number]: requests results from the specified number of past weeks.
- m[number]: requests results from the specified number of past months.
- y[number]: requests results from the specified number of past years.

Example usage should look like this:

```
String parameters = "&dateRestrict=d20";
```

or

```
String parameters = "&dateRestrict=y1";
```

I think, you can play with [APIs Explorer for this method](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/customsearch/v1/search.cse.list) for better understanding this parameter.

Also see:

- [Looking for Urgent solution regarding Google custom search API with
  Date-restrict parameter](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/customsearch/QoEQco_ejyU/Fhfxw9OPEqAJ)

Comment: I have tried this as well. Here is my URL that I have. http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=bank+fraud+new+york&dateRestrict=d1. However here is the second result I am getting: http://boss.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/12/12/a-win-for-small-businesses-in-bank-fraud-case/
Kabul

Comment: On the https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest page, Google recommends to use this URI: https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?parameters. I don't know where were you find ajax.googleapis.com URI but it probably is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying the same thing, and `dateRestrict` for an absolute time range didn't seem to work. The pages that were not in the date range also appeared. The workaround I found is to use the `sort` feature. The query will look something like this:

```
(q='search_term' , cx='search_engine_id', sort = 'date:r:yyyymmdd:yyyymmdd')
```

The `sort` feature allows us to sort and filter the date of the results to the time range specified.

Answer (score 1):

I know question asked for this awhile ago, I had the same problem.

Use `dateRestrict=d1` instead of `dateRestrict=d[1]`

The documentation made that a bit confusing. `[]` is used to show number as placeholder.